# Formula for the sequence -1/2, 0, 1/10, 0, -1/26, 0, 1/50, 0, -1/82

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came up with the formula (1/2)*((-1)^n-1)/(n^2+1), however, this would result in the sequence -1/2, 0, -1/10, 0, -1/26, 0....

I know the expression (-1)^n-1 is making the sequence alternate from negative to positive, any ideas on how to make it change as -1, 1 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1... or 
-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1...

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the question are different!

Comment: You can try your luck here: https://oeis.org/

Comment: What's wrong with saying $a_n = \frac {-1}{n^2 + 1}$ if $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $a_n = \frac 1{n^2+1}$ if $n$ is even and $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd?  There's no magic incantation that makes something described in a single expression more legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$a_n=\frac{-\sin(n\pi/2)}{n^2+1}?$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Look at every other term.

$$a_{n} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\
(-1)^{n}\cdot1/(4n^2-4n+1) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed as follows for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ starting with $n=1$:

- To get $1\,0\,1\,0\,1\,0\,1\, \ldots$ you may use $\frac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{2}$.
- To get $(-1)\, x \, 1\, y\, (-1)\, \ldots $ (where $x,y$ can be any number as we multiply them with the $0$ from the upper sequence) you may use the imaginary unit $i$: $i^{n-\lfloor n/4\rfloor  + 1}$

Putting this together you get

$$a_n = i^{n-\lfloor n/4\rfloor  + 1}\frac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{2(n^2+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one,$$(-1)^{n(n+1)(n+2)/2}$$ and for the second one $$(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$$